# How to get local notification everyday at specific time in ionic using cordova-plugin-local-notification

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I post this question 2 days ago , but i have not received any answer. 
I want to get local notification everyday at 10:00 AM . 
my code is:
And also some times i get notification then it can not removed by swapping on notification tray.

Please check my code and give me as soon as possible answer

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController, ToastController, AlertController  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MainpagePage } from "../pages/mainpage/mainpage";
import { LoginPage } from "../pages/login/login";
import { SplashPage } from "../pages/splash/splash";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { DbHandlerProvider } from '../providers/db-handler/db-handler';
import { LocationTracker } from '../providers/location-tracker/location-tracker';
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';
import { HttpService } from '../pages/services/httpService';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Diagnostic } from '@ionic-native/diagnostic';
declare let cordova: any;
import { LocationAccuracy } from '@ionic-native/location-accuracy';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any;
  db: SQLiteObject;
  time: any;
  arrTime: any = [];
  arrNotification: any = [];
  onResumeSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(public platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,private geolocation: Geolocation,
          private sqlite: SQLite, private dbHandlerProvider: DbHandlerProvider,
          public locationTracker: LocationTracker,private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,
          public httpService: HttpService, public toastCtrl: ToastController,private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
          private diagnostic: Diagnostic, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private locationAccuracy: LocationAccuracy) {

          this.dbHandlerProvider.createDatabase();
          this.backgroundMode.enable();
          if(localStorage.getItem('UserId') == null){
                this.rootPage = LoginPage;
          } else {
                this.rootPage = MainpagePage;
          } 
          platform.ready().then(() => {
             setTimeout(()=>{
                 this.pushNotification();
            },1000);
          statusBar.styleDefault();
        });
}


pushNotification() {
    var pushTime = moment().add(0, 'days').hours(10).minutes(0).seconds(0);
    let data = {
        text: 'Aaron Harper Notification ',
        every: 'day',
        firstAt: pushTime.toDate()
    }
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule(data);
}
}
```

in advance thank you...

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is happening? What else have you tried?  Can you show a hard coded time/date one that works?  For best results and getting answers, you should follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: errors are not get notification everyday.......

Comment: I shown my code in my question, if anything is remaining please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var pushTime = moment().add(0, 'days').hours(10).minutes(0).seconds(0);
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
  text: 'Tracking Enabled ',
  every: 'day',
  firstAt: pushTime.toDate()
});
```

It should schedule the first notification for today at 10am, then all next ones will be with interval of 1 day from the first one, meaning everyday at 10am.

Comment: Have you set time in future? you may try set time a few minutes ahead and ``every: 'minute'`` and check.

Comment: I try above code and i found that....
I run code now and i change date from phone setting to tomorrow at 10:00 AM then notification does not come but i change date 12th may to 13th may then notification is comes

Comment: why notification does not come at 12th may 10:00 AM

Comment: i also found that some times notification never comes

Comment: Post your code as an update to answer, then I call look at it.

Comment: Try to set ``firstAt`` in the past: ``moment().add(-1, 'days').hours(10).minutes(0).seconds(0);``

Comment: i tried now and get notification at 10 AM on 13th march..
On 12th march, no notification is come